# Enable roslaunch to log?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, topic, logger, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hy Community.

am going one step forward learning ROS, now I can define a file.launch like:

```
<launch>
    <node name="publishener1" pkg="abc_mmg" type="hello_world_publisher.py" args="--test" respawn="true" />
    <node name="subscriber1" pkg="abc_mmg" type="hello_world_subscriber.py" args="--test" respawn="true" />
</launch>
```

to start a  publisher and a subscriber that I wrote in the tutorials.. :) so far so good!

the issue is that I can't find to fix:

when I do

> rosclient@rosclient-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws$
> rosrun abc_mmg
> hello_world_publisher.py

my rosnode is working fine and I can see in the terminal the message it is publishing
same applies for the subscriber, every new callback msg is printed in the Terminal,

but when I do a roslaunch I dont see the msg anymore, as workaround I've found to open another terminal and do rostopic echo but how can I enable my Roslaunch to log in the terminal as before?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258512/enable-roslaunch-to-log?/) by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) on ROS Answers with karma: 424 on 2017-04-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to see your node's output every time, you can add `output="screen"` to the `<node>` tag in your launch file, or if you just want to see it once you can add `--screen` to the command line when you run roslaunch to send the output from all nodes to the console.

You can read the [roslaunch XML docs](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML) and [roslaunch command line docs](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Commandline%20Tools) for more details.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2